# C# SQL Server old data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following code in a dll that I use to query a SQL Server 2008 database

```
connectionString = @"Server=totmobdb-bod\live_mobile_data;Database=TM5Admin;User Id=ourusername;Password=ourpassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;";

dbConn.ReturnSingleTable("select Detail from dbo.Details where Name = 'RepairsReport'", mainConnectionString).Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();

    public DataTable ReturnSingleTable(string query, string connectionString)
    {

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                adapter.Fill(dataSet);
            };

        };

        DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0];

        return dataTable;

    }
```

I recently changed a value in the database through SQL Server Management Studio.

The problem is that the query in my code is some times bringing back the old value and sometimes bringing back the new value.

When I connect to the database using the same username/password as the query does I can see the correct value.

Any ideas folks?

Answer (score 0):

Although SQL Server Management Studio has implicit commit turned on,There might be a chance that changes which you made through your update query might not have committed data in the table,use `commit` after you execute the query.

Comment: i have just run the following in sql server, so fingers crossed it works. begin transaction
update dbo.Details set Detail = 'what we need' where Id = 52
commit transaction will update you when we find out Sid M

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, will try this in the morning, fingers crossed